# how to customise the ant design multi select

Tags: reactjs, components, antd

I want to design is

[image]

but my actual select option is

[image]

how to create this type of select option?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Antd's [Multiselect](https://ant.design/components/select) has a prop called `tagRender`. You should be able to use Antd's default tag component and create a wrapper around it with the comma and fixed spacing.

```
<Multiselect
   tagRender={(props) => {
     //console.log(props) //for exploration
     return <div className="wrapper">
        <Tag name={props.name}/>
        ,
     </div>
   }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find className of each element a then edit styles in css file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).